# Changing the mailed-by header in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, email-headers

All emails sent from my App Engine app (python) contain the following header:

```
mailed-by: <some random string>.apphosting.bounces.google.com
```

Is there a way to remove or change this header? It doesn't look professional to our clients.

Answer (score 0):

It's SPF authenticated. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?hl=en says "If a message was SPF authenticated, a 'mailed-by' header with the domain name will appear." In another case your e-mail can be recognized as spam.
It's "professionally" but If you client says No... . Start from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail and try to play with SPF records.